# Как при запросе чисел в генераторе списка реализовать "счетчик" j-го элемента?

Tags: python

```
a = [i for i in (int(input('Введите число', j)) for j in range(5)) if i % 10 == 0]
```

суть в том, чтобы при запросе числа было выведено текстом, какое число по счету мы запрашиваем, например

```
Введите число 1:
23
Введите число 2:
.....
```

но при выше показанном коде выдает ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` принимает только один аргумент поэтому строку надо объединить с числом. Это возможно сделать так:

```
input('Введите число ' + str(j) +": ")
```

либо используя `f`-строки

```
input(f'Введите число {j}: ")
```

но будет выводиться не с `1`, а с `0`.Это можно исправить заменив `j` на `j + 1` либо изменив `range` на `range(1, 6)`

Answer (score 0):

`input` принимает только один аргумент, в отличие от `print`. А было бы удобно.

Внутрь `input` вставляется f-строка. Ещё удобно поменять `range` чтобы нумерация была с единицы:

```
a = [i for i in (int(input(f'Введите число {j}: ')) for j in range(1, 6)) if i % 10 == 0]
```